GitHub Pages Deployment Fails with 404 Error and Actions Unable to Enable for Repository
My username is simimap on Github. Initially, I created a repository named simimap and successfully accessed the page https://simimap.github.io/simimap. However, I later discovered that the page returned a 404 error. Upon checking the deployment logs for November 29, I found the following issue:
Status: Failed to deploy (completed)
Failed to deploy to github-pages by simimap via pages-build-deployment #10

According to the logs, this issue occurred when updating the styles.css file. The detailed information is as follows:
Annotations
4 errors
deploy
Canceling since a higher priority waiting request for pages build and deployment @ main exists
report-build-status
The operation was canceled.
report-build-status
Canceling since a higher priority waiting request for pages build and deployment @ main exists
pages build and deployment
Canceling since a higher priority waiting request for pages build and deployment @ main exists

Afterward, I tried several actions, including:
Changing the repository visibility from public to private and then back to public;
Switching the branch from main to gh-pages;
Unpublishing the site and other related operations.

However, none of these actions triggered the build and deployment process for GitHub Pages. Additionally, after unpublishing the site, the message Your site is live at https://simimap.github.io/simimap disappeared, and the page remains inaccessible with a 404 error.
I then renamed the repository from simimap to web-old and created a new repository named simimap. In the new repository, I attempted to deploy a simple hello world HTML file, but it still resulted in a 404 error. Furthermore, the build and deployment process for Pages was not triggered. When I visited the Actions page, I noticed that I could create a new action.
I manually created a .github/workflows/pages.yml file. However, upon revisiting the Actions page, I encountered the following message:
Workflows aren’t being run on this repository
GitHub Actions is not currently enabled on this repository.

When I clicked the Enable Actions on this repository button, I received the error: “Unable to enable Actions for this repository.”
To troubleshoot, I deployed the same hello world project to a repository under another GitHub account, and it worked perfectly. However, it continues to return a 404 error under my account.
I am currently unsure why this issue persists. Could you please help analyze the cause and provide a solution?
